# How to change login details so they are stored in cookies so user remains logged in and not expire

Tags: php, session, cookies, browser, authentication

I want to create a simple login system where the user logs in, then it will keeps the details of user logged in stored and they will always be logged in until they have either clicked on the log out link. Now I heard that is better to user cookies in order to do this. Below is the login page:

teacherlogin.php script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php

// connect to the database
include('connect.php');
include('member.php');

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }

  // required variables (make them explciit no need for foreach loop)
  $teacherusername = (isset($_POST['teacherusername'])) ? $_POST['teacherusername'] : '';
  $teacherpassword = (isset($_POST['teacherpassword'])) ? $_POST['teacherpassword'] : '';
  $loggedIn = false;
  $active = true;

  if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){
      echo "You are already Logged In: <b>{$_SESSION['teacherforename']} {$_SESSION['teachersurname']}</b> | <a href='./menu.php'>Go to Menu</a> | <a href='./teacherlogout.php'>Logout</a>";
  }
  else{

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      $teacherpassword = md5(md5("g3f".$teacherpassword."rt4"));  

    // don't use $mysqli->prepare here
    $query = "SELECT TeacherId, TeacherForename, TeacherSurname, TeacherUsername, TeacherPassword, Active FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherUsername = ? AND TeacherPassword = ? LIMIT 1";
    // prepare query
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$teacherusername,$teacherpassword);
    // execute query
    $stmt->execute(); 
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherId, $dbTeacherForename,$dbTeacherSurname,$dbTeacherUsername,$dbTeacherPassword, $dbActive);

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
      if ($teacherusername == $dbTeacherUsername && $teacherpassword == $dbTeacherPassword) {
if ($dbActive == 0) {
    $loggedIn = false;
    $active = false;
    echo "You Must Activate Your Account from Email to Login";
}else {
    $loggedIn = true;
    $active = true;
      $_SESSION['teacherid'] = $dbTeacherId;
      $_SESSION['teacherusername'] = $dbTeacherUsername;
}
      }
    }

    if ($loggedIn == true){
      $_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $dbTeacherForename;
      $_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $dbTeacherSurname;
      header( 'Location: menu.php' ) ;
      die();
    }

    if (!$loggedIn && $active && isset($_POST)) {
    echo "<span style='color: red'>The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again</span>";
    }

       /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
  }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Teacher Login</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TeacherLoginStyle.css">
   </head>
<body>

                <?php
        include('noscript.php');
        ?>

    <h1>TEACHER LOGIN</h1>

  <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="teachLoginForm">        
  <p>Username</p><p><input type="text" name="teacherusername" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher Username-->
  <p>Password</p><p><input type="password" name="teacherpassword" /></p>  <!-- Enter Teacher Password--> 
  <p><input id="loginSubmit" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" /></p>
  </form>

  <a href="./forgotpass.php">Forgot Password</a>

</body>

<?php

}

?>
```

In the code above the user will enter in their username and password in the relevant text inputs. When they submit their login details, it will check in the database to see if their login details match in the database.

Now what I want to do is store the details of user's username and id in a php script (member.php) so that it knows which user is logged in. But at the moment I am using $SESSION to do this which contains short amount of time:

member.php page:

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherid'])) {

      $userid = $_SESSION['teacherid'];

  }

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherusername'])) {

      $username = $_SESSION['teacherusername'];

  }

        ?>
```

How can I change the code above to get cookies involved so that the user's details in the member page will stay for an unlimited time (until they log out of course).

UPDATE:

OK here is the `Teacher` Table in the database:

```
TeacherId (auto PK) TeacherForename  TeacherSurname TeacherUsername, TeacherPassword
1                   John             Parks          j.parks          b018460fba79b
2                   Mary             Little         u0876555         a33rfe3tn12e3
3                   Jim              Owen           owensjimmy       fkof04r3fk422
```

So are you saying first of all add a column SessionId into table above and store in a complex id for each user e.g. `34dekfm45345`.

Then I will really need your help in order to be able to see the code on how to find the correct SessionId and delete the SessionId.

UPDATE 2:

So if I understand correctly, below is what the php scripts should look like:

teacherlogin.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <?php

    // connect to the database
    include('connect.php');
    include('member.php');
    include('sessionuser.php');

      /* check connection */
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        die();
      }

      // required variables (make them explciit no need for foreach loop)
      $teacherusername = (isset($_POST['teacherusername'])) ? $_POST['teacherusername'] : '';
      $teacherpassword = (isset($_POST['teacherpassword'])) ? $_POST['teacherpassword'] : '';
      $loggedIn = false;
      $active = true;

      if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){
          echo "You are already Logged In: <b>{$_SESSION['teacherforename']} {$_SESSION['teachersurname']}</b> | <a href='./menu.php'>Go to Menu</a> | <a href='./teacherlogout.php'>Logout</a>";
      }
      else{

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

          $teacherpassword = md5(md5("g3f".$teacherpassword."rt4"));  

        // don't use $mysqli->prepare here
        $query = "SELECT TeacherId, TeacherForename, TeacherSurname, TeacherUsername, TeacherPassword, Active FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherUsername = ? AND TeacherPassword = ? LIMIT 1";
        // prepare query
        $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
        // You only need to call bind_param once
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$teacherusername,$teacherpassword);
        // execute query
        $stmt->execute(); 
        // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
        $stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherId, $dbTeacherForename,$dbTeacherSurname,$dbTeacherUsername,$dbTeacherPassword, $dbActive);

        while($stmt->fetch()) {
          if ($teacherusername == $dbTeacherUsername && $teacherpassword == $dbTeacherPassword) {
    if ($dbActive == 0) {
        $loggedIn = false;
        $active = false;
        echo "You Must Activate Your Account from Email to Login";
    }else {
        $loggedIn = true;
        $active = true;
          $_SESSION['teacherid'] = $dbTeacherId;
          $_SESSION['teacherusername'] = $dbTeacherUsername;
    }
          }
        }

        if ($loggedIn == true){
          $_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $dbTeacherForename;
          $_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $dbTeacherSurname;
          header( 'Location: menu.php' ) ;
          die();
        }

        if (!$loggedIn && $active && isset($_POST)) {
        echo "<span style='color: red'>The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again</span>";
        }

           /* close statement */
        $stmt->close();

        /* close connection */
        $mysqli->close();
      }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Teacher Login</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TeacherLoginStyle.css">
       </head>
    <body>

                    <?php
            include('noscript.php');
            ?>

        <h1>TEACHER LOGIN</h1>

      <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="teachLoginForm">        
      <p>Username</p><p><input type="text" name="teacherusername" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher Username-->
      <p>Password</p><p><input type="password" name="teacherpassword" /></p>  <!-- Enter Teacher Password--> 
      <p><input id="loginSubmit" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" /></p>
      </form>

      <a href="./forgotpass.php">Forgot Password</a>

    </body>

    <?php

    }

    ?>
```

I have not changed the code where it checks to see if user is currently logged in or not, do I change it from `if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){` to anything relelvant?. I included the `include(sessionuser.php) code above

member.php script:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_SESSION['teacherid'])) {

          $userid = $_SESSION['teacherid'];

      }

    if (isset($_SESSION['teacherusername'])) {

          $username = $_SESSION['teacherusername'];

      }

            ?>
```

Do I still need the member.php script above?

sessionuser.php script:

```
$sessionUserID = false;

if (isset($_COOKIE['sessionUserID']) && preg_match('/^[a-z9-0]{32}$/i) {
    $sessionUserID = $_COOKIE['sessionUserID'];

    // Get the session details from the database
    $sql = 'SELECT s.*, t.* FROM SessionUser s LEFT JOIN Teacher t ON s.TeacherId=t.TeacherId WHERE s.SessionUserId=:SessionUserId';
    $aParams = array(':SessionUserId' => $sessionUserID)
    $sessionRow = $stmnt->fetch();
    if ($sessionRow) {
        // User is logged in, and you have details in $sessionRow
        // At this point, you can also validate other info such as the UserAgent, IP etc. All forgable, but can help add a littel security.
    } else {
        // Passed an invalid / expired session ID
        $sessionUserID = false;
    }
}

// If you don't have a session, create one
if (!$sessionUserID) {
    // Create a session user ID - make it non sequential
    // You should put this in a loop and check $sessionID is unique. Insert will fail is not unique
    $sessionUserID = md5(time() . uniqid());
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO SessionUser(SessionUserId, TeacherId)
              VALUES(:SessionUserId, 0)';
    $aParams = array(':SessionUserId' => $sessionUserID)
    $smnt->execute();

    // Default session details
    $sessionRow = array('TeacherId'=>0);

    // Now the cookie part
    setcookie('sessionUserID', $sessionUserID, time() + howLongYouWant, '/');
}

// Not check for user logging in.
if (UserLogsIn) {
    if ($sessionRow['teacher_id'] > 0) {
         // Already logged in!?
    } else {

        $sql = 'UPDATE SessionUser SET Teacher_id=:TeacherId WHERE SessionUserId=:SessionUserId';
        $aParams = array(':TeacherId'=>$TeacherId, ':SessionUserId' => $sessionUserID);
        $smnt->execute();

        // After a form post, always redirect to the same page or another page - stops the "do you want to resent this data" message on back button
        // DO NOT echo anything before this point.
        header('location: this page');
        exit();
    }
} elseif (UserLogsOut) {
    if ($sessionRow['TeacherId'] == 0) {
         // Not Logged In!?
    } else {

        $sql = 'UPDATE SessionUser SET TeacherId=0 WHERE SessionUserd=:SessionUserid';
        $aParams = array(':session_id' => $sessionID);
        $smnt->execute();

        // After a form post, always redirect to the same page or another page - stops the "do you want to resent this data" message on back button
        // DO NOT echo anything before this point.
        header('location: this page');
        exit();
    }
}
```

IS it correct that the sessionuser.php script code contains all of the code above? I have changed the code to try and match the database table below:

SessionUser Table:

```
SessionUserId (CHAR32) PK
TeacherId (INT) //matches TeacherId field in teacher table
```

Is update 2 correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple (but wrong) answer is that you replace all `$_SESSION['blah'] = $value` with `setcookie('blah', $value, time() + ages);`

But the problem you have is that you are storing user information in the session - and that information, if you store in a cookie, can easily be changed.

So you need a local (on server) way of storing the personal details, and a reference number to recall those details - essentially you need to replicate sessions but using your own database (or file store).

Commonly this is done in a database: you create a "session" database, give each user a unique sessionID (hard to guess, not a straight numeric) and then store that session ID in a cookie, and store the personal details in the database. Then you get a session cookie, recall their details from the database. When they log out, delete the entry in the databse etc. If the server reboots and you lose sessions, your session data is safe as it's in the database - the user is always logged in until you don't want it.

So there's a simple answer, and the real, more complex answer.

---

EDIT:

As requested, an off-the-cuff process. I've missed off error checking and all that jazz for DB calls. This should get you started.

```
// Create a DB with the following structure
session_id CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY
teacher_id INT(mathc your teachers table)

// Check for cookie, validate it's an expected format
$sessionID = false;

if (isset($_COOKIE['sessionID']) && preg_match('/^[a-z9-0]{32}$/i) {
    $sessionID = $_COOKIE['sessionID'];

    // Get the session details from the database
    $sql = 'SELECT s.*, t.* FROM sessions s LEFT JOIN teachers t ON s.teacher_id=t.teacher_id WHERE s.session_id=:session_id';
    $aParams = array(':session_id' => $sessionID)
    $sessionRow = $stmnt->fetch();
    if ($sessionRow) {
        // User is logged in, and you have details in $sessionRow
        // At this point, you can also validate other info such as the UserAgent, IP etc. All forgable, but can help add a littel security.
    } else {
        // Passed an invalid / expired session ID
        $sessionID = false;
    }
}

// If you don't have a session, create one
if (!$sessionID) {
    // Create a session ID - make it non sequential
    // You should put this in a loop and check $sessionID is unique. Insert will fail is not unique
    $sessionID = md5(time() . uniqid());
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO sessions(session_id, teacher_id)
              VALUES(:session_id, 0)';
    $aParams = array(':session_id' => $sessionID)
    $smnt->execute();

    // Default session details
    $sessionRow = array('teacher_id'=>0);

    // Now the cookie part
    setcookie('sessionID', $sessionID, time() + howLongYouWant, '/');
}

// Not check for user logging in.
if (UserLogsIn) {
    if ($sessionRow['teacher_id'] > 0) {
         // Already logged in!?
    } else {

        $sql = 'UPDATE sessions SET teacher_id=:teacher_id WHERE session_id=:session_id';
        $aParams = array(':teacher_id'=>$teacher_id, ':session_id' => $sessionID);
        $smnt->execute();

        // After a form post, always redirect to the same page or another page - stops the "do you want to resent this data" message on back button
        // DO NOT echo anything before this point.
        header('location: this page');
        exit();
    }
} elseif (UserLogsOut) {
    if ($sessionRow['teacher_id'] == 0) {
         // Not Logged In!?
    } else {

        $sql = 'UPDATE sessions SET teacher_id=0 WHERE session_id=:session_id';
        $aParams = array(':session_id' => $sessionID);
        $smnt->execute();

        // After a form post, always redirect to the same page or another page - stops the "do you want to resent this data" message on back button
        // DO NOT echo anything before this point.
        header('location: this page');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind robbie, as I am assuming you have very good knowledge of this and I never done it before, would you mind providing sample code on what I need to do like in a step by step process. I think it will help me a lot and will help future visitors who look at this question and are equally stuck :) Take your time, no rush because I know you will be busy with other things

Comment: Edited with pseduo code. It's not perfect, but is enough to get your started, and links into your example / project

Comment: sorry for lateness been asleep, I just want to know that does this code go in the member.php script or does it go on the top of the teacherlogin.php script? Also for all the other pages in the script what line(s) of code do I need to include to check if user is currently logged in or not logged in? At moment if you look at my teacherlogin.php page I am using `if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){` to check if user is already logged in or not

Comment: Everyting before the `If (UserLogsIn)` is generic session handler that applies to every page when you want to know if a user is logged in or not. This goes in an include or function near the top of every page. The rest (`is (UserLogIn)` bit) is how you handle a user submitting a log in or log out request.

Comment: I have included an UPDATE 2: section in the question, can you please have a look and tell me that the way I am implementing the scripts is the correct or not please

Comment: Also when you said it is not perfect but should be able to get mem started, what issues should I be looking st in order to improve the pseduo code? Is it more security or do I need to add things into the code to get it working?

Comment: Update 2: It's not totally correct, no. You need the "is the user logging in" bit in the login.php (currently in session_user). You also still reference $_SESSION and variables derived from it - you don't need $_SESSION at all, everything is in the sessionRow. To improve the Pseudo code, you'll need ot add error chacking on SQL statements, login feedback etc - to cope with the unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to extend the session expiry time. usually the session expire when the browser is closed, you can change this from ini settings. See http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php
Wont be exactly what you are looking for, i.e. forever, but having an extended time might be a reasonable solution.

Comment: at the moment that is what I am doing, I have set the session maxlife to 12 hours. It isn't the best solution in order to make the best reliable login system but it is a temporary fix for my application. But I do want to change it so user is logged in unlimited time until they are logged out or close browser

Comment: What you are after is "Remember me" option rather than switching to cookie for login (which is a bad idea). So look for a way of implementing remember me option. Let me know if you want more information.

Comment: I will definite need more information on this, I have never created a remember me option before. Need help on coding it as well

Comment: Excuse my delay. Basically you need a second cookie which identifies the user. In the simplest form, say you store the ID of the logged in users in a cookie called __LOGGED_IN_ID__. When a user comes to your site and if the __LOGGED_IN_ID__ is set, you know that the user has logged in previously and you also know the user ID, hence you log the user in with the given ID. Sounds easy, but the problem is anyone can set a cookie, so you need to make it more secure. Again, do some research on making this more secure and do come back if you need more info. :)